# mysql_fetch_array() and mysql_query() problems

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I keep getting this error in my error log and I'm not sure why. I've looked everywhere and Google'd it, but I'm lost and I need help:

```
[Wed Mar 27 02:14:56 2013] [error] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to
 be resource, null given in /nas/wp/www/cluster-1434/XXXXXXXX/wp-content/themes/mytheme
/groups/single/home.php on line 23
[Wed Mar 27 02:14:56 2013] [error] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects 
 parameter  
1 to be resource, null given in /nas/wp/www/cluster-1434/XXXXXXXX/wp-content/themes
/mytheme/groups/single/home.php on line 24
```

This is the code it is referencing:

```
$getlatlong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcity WHERE zip='".$url[2]."'",$con);
$ll = mysql_fetch_array($getlatlong);
```

This is the full code if you need it:

```
<?php
global $bp;
global $current_user;
$group_name = $bp->groups->current_group->name;
$group_id = $bp->groups->current_group->id;
$groupll = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, $meta_key = 'latlong');
$groupnamecount = strlen($group_name);
$groupcity = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, $meta_key = 'city');
$groupstate = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, $meta_key = 'state');
$mapaddress = $group_name.'+'.$groupcity.'+'.$groupstate;
if ($groupnamecount == '5')
{
$grouptype = "zip"; 
}
if ($grouptype == "zip") {

$url = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$zip = $url[2]; 
$getlatlong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE zip='".$url[2]."'",$con);
$ll = mysql_fetch_array($getlatlong);
} else {
$groupcity = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, $meta_key = 'city');
$groupstate = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, $meta_key = 'state');
$mapaddress = $group_name.'+'.$groupcity.'+'.$groupstate;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Issue was that $con was declared further down the code. Once I fixed that, it worked perfectly. Thanks to all that answered!

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: I think may be your $url[2] providing null value.It may be Array index out of bound. you have to append the " or die(mysql_error())" to the mysql_query. Now your query become mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error()). So you get the exact error. You got my Point.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you explain?

Comment: @michaelrmcneill your sql string is built by using user input directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your connection $con, it isn't connecting and returning null.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to put the `$conn` in `mysql_query()` function its just intended to execute you SQL Statements because you already do so connect to database using `mysql_select_db()`
with your `$con` settings just like below..

```
  $getlatlong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcity WHERE zip='".$url[2]."'",$con);
    $ll = mysql_fetch_array($getlatlong);
```

First your connection should lool like this..

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);  // mysql config
mysql_select_db('databasename',$conn);    // connection to database
```

then query like this..

```
$getlatlong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcity WHERE zip='".$url[2]."'");
        $ll = mysql_fetch_array($getlatlong);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$con` variable is either never defined, or the connection failed. PHP will automatically use the last MySQL connection made if you don't specify the connection parameter at all, like so:

```
$getlatlong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE zip='". $url[2] ."'");
```